# (Gatsby+Contentful) Creating Category Pages Programmatically?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I was wondering how to set up category pages programmatically with Gatsby.JS when using Contentful as CMS?

I know that in MDX you can simply configure your gatsby-node.js to something like this to create the category pages programmatically:

```
  result.data.allMDX.categories.distinct.forEach((category) => {
createPage({
  path: `/${category}`,
  component: path.resolve(`src/templates/category-template.js`),
  context: {
    category,
  },
})
```

How can I achieve the same using Contentful? I cant find any good resources online. Nobody is talking about how to set up category pages programmatically with Gatsby + Contentful.

Heres my current gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
  query GetStrains {
    strains: allContentfulStrains(filter: {node_locale: {eq: "en-US"}}) {
      nodes {
        slug
      }
    }
    categories: allContentfulStrains {
      distinct(field: category)
    }
  }
  `)


  result.data.strains.nodes.forEach(strain => {
    createPage({
      path: `/strains/${strain.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/strain-template.js`),
      context: {
        slug: strain.slug
      },
    })
  })

  result.data.allContentfulStrains.categories.distinct.forEach((category) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/${category}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/category-template-strains.js`),
      context: {
        category,
      },
    })
  })
```

As you can see above ive tried adding categories the same way as with MDX but its not working (OFC).

I would really appreciate feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Since neither Contentful or Gatsby have any notion of a “category”, and there is not any convention for a page that might represent a category in your app, it's hard to expect that there would be prior art for this.

If what you're trying to do is to create pages based on the `category` field of another node (e.g. `contentfulStrain`), you would instead need to query for those nodes and collate/de-dupe as needed before calling `createPage` for each unique `category`. Something like this:

```js
const {
  data: {
    strains: { nodes: strains },
  },
} = await graphql(`
  {
    strains: allContentfulStrains(filter: { node_locale: { eq: "en-US" } }) {
      nodes {
        slug
        category
      }
    }
  }
`)

strains
  // Convert from strains to categories
  .reduce((categories, strain) => {
    categories.add(strain.category)
    return categories
  }, new Set())

  // Create a page for each category
  .forEach((category) => {
    createPage({
      // TODO: use a slugify function to create a url-friendly slug
      // for `category` before using it as the path.
      path: `/${category}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/category-template-strains.js`),
      context: {
        category,
      },
    })
  })
```

Then in `src/templates/category-template-strains.js` you would have a query that filters `allContentfulStrains` on the `category` field and retrieves any other data you need to build your category page.